# Single Sign On Framework

Tags: java, single-sign-on, cas, saml-2.0, openam

I want to implement a SSO Framework. My requirement is thus:

Once a user log's into particular website and he clicks on an external link, he should not be asked to verify his credentials again.

EDIT: Here, I have control over the 'external link' that I speak of. The first link that the person sign's into can provide me credentials or other information that I require, but I have no control over it.

I researched a bit, and found CAS to be relevant for my requirement. But, I don't want the end user to login to CAS initially, I need a framework that receives the credentials from the currently logged in website and uses the same to login to the other external site. Security is, of course, an important factor. Can you please give me some pointers/ ideas as to how to go about designing such a framework?

Comment: Your question is fairly generic for a topic that can be very detailed.  The implementation you use depends on a lot of factors such as which of the apps you have control over, who is the Identity Provider (IdP), what SSO protocol you will be using.  If you can clarify a bit it will help to target what you are looking for.  Generally, though Juned's answer below should give you a good place to start.  Also, check out [this site](http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF610/Browser-based+SSO) for a good explanation of SAML.

Comment: I have edited my question. I am still weighing my options about the SSO protocol that best suits my requirement. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you're describing, it sounds like an Identity Provider (IdP) initiated SAML profile would meet your requirements (a good visual representation of this is [here](http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF610/IdP-Initiated+SSO--POST)).  The original web site your user is logged in to will function as the Identity Provider.  Once a user is authenticated with that application, they will then be able to access your external application by clicking a link.  Instead of being directed to a log in page for your application, the original app will instead forward the user's authorization details via SAML to you where the signature will be verified and possibly checked with the identity provider. If everything checks out, the user will be redirected to the requested resource from your app without having to sign in.

Note, that the above describes the *protocol* of the SSO.  There are many different frameworks that support SAML that you can use.  Two that you can research are [Shibboleth](http://shibboleth.net/) and, as already mentioned, [OpenAM](http://forgerock.com/what-we-offer/open-identity-stack/openam/).

This is a rather simplified explanation based on limited details, but hopefully it will help lead you towards a solution.  I would recommend doing a good bit of research on the protocols and frameworks available before making your decision.  Also, a proof of concept never hurts to prove out the solution will work for you before investing in it to a point of no return.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenAM](http://openam.forgerock.org/) should help you:

> OpenAM provides open source Authentication, Authorization, Entitlement
>   and Federation software. Through OpenAM, the community actively
>   continues development of OpenSSO.
>
> **OpenAM provides core identity services to simplify the implementation of transparent single sign-on (SSO) as a security
>   component in a network infrastructure**. OpenAM provides the
>   foundation for integrating diverse web applications that might
>   typically operate against a disparate set of identity repositories and
>   are hosted on a variety of platforms such as web and application
>   servers.

Comment: Additionally, if the application that needs to receive the SSO token is not owned by you and doesn't support SSO you can use [OpenIG](http://openig.forgerock.org/) to act as a reverse proxy and plug the app into the framework.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Juned. OpenAM requires the provider to implement OAuth2 protocol, but in my case I don't own the provider. I have control only over the application to which the link redirects.

Comment: OpenAM does not really need OAuth2, that is an option you can use for A&A

Answer (score 1):

On the wikipedia page List of single sign-on implementations you can find a list of [SSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_single_sign-on_implementations) implementations, there is a column indicating the licence.

Read about jboss sso from [here](http://www.jboss.org/jbosssso).